# Do Users Have To Login Through Facebook For My Custom Like Button To Post To Their Facebook Profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to use a custom like button which uses the og.like action to post to a user's Facebook timeline when they like a post on my website as detailed here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes

It says they will need to grant my website Publish_Actions in order to do this.  Does that mean they have to log into my site using Facebook, or can they authorize it just logging in using my existing login system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible without authorization by using FB.ui share:

```js
FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.likes',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  })
}, function(response){});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  This would cause a dialog to pop up asking if they wanted to post it to Facebook like the regular share button correct?  It would be best if it just posted to Facebook when they liked something, without an additional pop-up appearing (Instagram does this.)  Is that possible without the user logging in through Facebook?

Comment: that´s not possible without authorization (and publish_actions)

Comment: instagram is using facebook authorization with their app

Comment: Which would require the user to initially log into my app website through Facebook and asking for Publish_Actions permissions correct?

Comment: exactly - and you would need to get publish_actions approved too. a lot of work and waiting.